# The static method getDBConnection() from the type DBConnection should be accessed in a static way

Tags: java

I have got a singleton class as shown  below for accessing Database connection as

```
public class DBConnection {
    private static volatile DBConnection instance;
    private static DataSource dataSource;
    private DBConnection(){ 
    }
    public static synchronized DBConnection getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DBConnection();
        }
        return instance;
    }
    static {
        try {
            dataSource = (DataSource) new InitialContext()
                    .lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/MySQLDataSource");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            try {
                throw new Exception("'jndifordbconc' not found in JNDI", e);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                logger.error("Error description", e);
            }
        }
    }

    public static Connection getDBConnection() {
        try {
            return dataSource.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.error("Error description", e);
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

And when i am trying to access the DBConnection this way

**SeperateClass**

**Here i am getting the yellow warning**

```
  public String fetchGlobalIndicesData(@QueryParam("region_name") String region_name )
    {
       Connection dbConnection = null;
        String selectsql = "";

        try
        {

            dbConnection = DBConnection.getInstance().getDBConnection();
            selectpstmt = dbConnection.prepareStatement(selectsql);
            selectpstmt.setString(1, region_name);
            selectRset = selectpstmt.executeQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.error("Error description",e);
        }

    }
```

Eclipse IDE is giving me a yellow warning saying

```
The static method getDBConnection() from the type DBConnection should be accessed in a static way
```

Could you please tell me whats the proper way of doing this ??

I modified my code as

```
public static Connection getDBConnection() {
    try {
        return getInstance().dataSource.getConnection();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("Error description", e);
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: did you try ``DBConnection.getDBConnection()``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Berger mentioned, you defined the method as static, so you have to call it as he mentioned.

If you don't want it static, you can modify your code by removing static from the getDBConnection method and call it as:

```
DBConnection.getInstance().getDBConnection()
```

The code above is already correct in your fetchGlobalIndicesData method.

Just for the sake of it:

```
public static Connection getDBConnection()
```

Becomes:

```
public Connection getDBConnection()
```

This way, getInstance will initialize a DBConnection instance, and the static initializer block to init your datasource should fire. Then when you call getDBConnection, your code should work fine.

Comment: i modified my code as per your comments , please see my edited question .

Comment: @Preethi Jain I think your edit is incorrect. The content of your getDBConnection was fine. Removing the static keyword form your getDBConnection method is all you have to do. See my editted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Since it is static, you are supposed to call the method directly on the class , not on an instance of the class :

```
DBConnection.getDBConnection()
```

Calling the method on an instance has no sense, though it is possible.

Comment: Ok , then when does the getInstance() method gets called ?? since instance is null .

Comment: Remove the static keyword from your method, it will give you the expected result. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

That is an static method, you can remove the **static** keyword of the `getDBConnection()` signature or use `DBConnection.getDBConnection()`